# How can I evaluate: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2 + 4x} - \sqrt{x^2 - 5x}$

Tags: limits

I need to find this limit:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2 + 4x} - \sqrt{x^2 - 5x}$$

The answer I got from using the limit laws is $\sqrt{\infty} - \sqrt{\infty}$.

How do I proceed now?

**Added** I took the conjugate of the function and I got a new and probably better function to work with: $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{9x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x} + \sqrt{x^2-5x}}$$

Comment: I took the conjucate of the function and i got a new and probally better function to work with: 9x / square root ((x^2)+4x) + square root ((x^2)-5x)

Comment: I took what you wrote as a comment and added it to your post. I also edited the rest of your post.  Click on the "edit" link right below the tag (limits) in your posted question, and you can see the formatting I used. It makes use of mathjax, similar to latex.  Search for "mathjax tutorial".  You can also pick up a lot of the formatting tricks by clicking on that same "edit" link to see how anyone formatted their post.

Comment: Here is the link to the [mathjax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which will be a nice reference for learning mathjax (how to format math on this site.)

Comment: thank you so much @amWhy for the edit, and link to the useful site on formatting math problems

Comment: You're welcome!  Since you're new to the site, this quick [tour of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will help you get an overall picture of how this site operates. It comes from the "help" tab which should be on the right of the page's top banner, right next to the box that let's you search for questions and their answers before posting.

Answer (score 6):

$$\\ \lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+4x } -\sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }-5x }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { \left( \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+4x } -\sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }-5x }  \right) \left( \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+4x } +\sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }-5x }  \right)  }{ \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+4x } +\sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }-5x }  }  } =\\ =\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { 9x }{ \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+4x } +\sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }-5x }  }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { 9x }{ \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }\left( 1+\frac { 4 }{ x }  \right)  } +\sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }\left( 1-\frac { 5 }{ x }  \right)  }  }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { 9x }{ \left| x \right| \left( \sqrt { 1+\frac { 4 }{ x }  } +\sqrt { 1-\frac { 5 }{ x }  }  \right)  }  } =\\ \overset { if\quad x>0 }{ = } \lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { 9x }{ x\left( \sqrt { 1+\frac { 4 }{ x }  } +\sqrt { 1-\frac { 5 }{ x }  }  \right)  }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { 9 }{ \left( \sqrt { 1+\frac { 4 }{ x }  } +\sqrt { 1-\frac { 5 }{ x }  }  \right)  }  } =\frac { 9 }{ \sqrt { 1+0 } +\sqrt { 1-0 }  } =\frac { 9 }{ 2 } $$

Comment: hey haqnatural how did you type all that in that box? I wanted to show my work but I wasn't able to type it the way you did it. Also I don't understand how you did the last two steps. If you can explain much would be appreciated/

Comment: use this program http://s1.daumcdn.net/editor/fp/service_nc/pencil/Pencil_chromestore.html

Comment: @PoloKing987654321Er He divided it by $x$

Comment: I'm sorry i still don't understand.

Comment: Thank you so much haqnatural this is clear, and thanks to @A---B for clarifying it more. Thank you everyone for your help, and I hope you guys have a wonderful day.

Comment: you're welcome)

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{(x^2)+4x} - \sqrt{(x^2)-5x}$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} {(x^2)+4x - (x^2)+5x\over\sqrt{(x^2)+4x} +\sqrt{(x^2)-5x}}$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} {9x\over\sqrt{(x^2)+4x} +\sqrt{(x^2)-5x}}$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} {9\over\sqrt{(x^2)/x^2+4x/x^2} +\sqrt{(x^2)/x^2-5x/x^2}}$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} {9\over\sqrt{1+4/x} +\sqrt{1-5/x}}$$

$${9\over\sqrt{1} +\sqrt{1}}={9\over 2}$$

Comment: Thank you so much this makes more sense now!

Comment: (IMHO, this is much clearer than haqnatural's answer, at least in layout)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply and divide by $$\sqrt{x^2+4x} +\sqrt{x^2-5x}$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{9x}{\sqrt{x^2+4x} +\sqrt{x^2-5x}}$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{9}{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{x} +\frac{\sqrt{x^2-5x}}{x}}$$

Comment: @amWhy It was in comment section . So I didn't pay attention to it.

Comment: Welcome , Try to add your work in question instead of comment section .It become easier for help .Formatting tips here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

If you know Differential Calculus, you may also use L'hopital's Rule to solve for the limit. Just as a recap, one instance of L'hopital's Rule states:

> Given $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ with some arbitrary limit to $c$ imposed on it, if all of the following constraints are met:
>
> > $\lim_{x\rightarrow{c}} f(x) = 0 $
> >
> > $\lim_{x\rightarrow{c}} g(x) = 0$
> >
> > $\lim_{x\rightarrow{c}}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=L$
>
> then
>
> > $\lim_{x\rightarrow{c}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L$

Now, we have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{x^2+4x}-\sqrt{x^2-5x}$$

which is obviously not in the form of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ as needed. However, we can put it into one, like so, as long as $x>0$:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{x^2+4x}-\sqrt{x^2-5x} = $$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x\Bigg(\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}}-\sqrt{1-\frac{5}{x}}\Bigg)=$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}}-\sqrt{1-\frac{5}{x}}}{x^{-1}} = \frac{0}{0}$$

Now we have the form we want and we found the limit, which is in the indeterminite form $\frac{0}{0}$. We also have our two functions, which are

$$f(x)=\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}}-\sqrt{1-\frac{5}{x}}$$
$$g(x)=x^{-1}=\frac{1}{x}$$

Now we have to do find the derivative of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, which are:

$$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(1+\frac{4}{x}\bigg)^{0.5}\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(1+\frac{4}{x}\bigg)-\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(1-\frac{5}{x}\bigg)^{0.5}\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(1-\frac{5}{x}\bigg)=$$
$$-\frac{4}{2x^{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}}}-\frac{5}{2x^{2}\sqrt{1-\frac{5}{x}}}=$$
$$\frac{-4\sqrt{1-\frac{5}{x}}-5\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}}}{2x^{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}}\sqrt{1-\frac{5}{x}}}$$
$$g'(x)=-x^{-2}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

And finally

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\Bigg(\frac{-4\sqrt{1-\frac{5}{x}}-5\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}}}{2x^{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}}\sqrt{1-\frac{5}{x}}}\Bigg)}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x^{2}\Bigg(\frac{4\sqrt{1-\frac{5}{x}}+5\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}}}{2x^{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}}\sqrt{1-\frac{5}{x}}}\Bigg)=$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{4\sqrt{1-\frac{5}{x}}+5\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}}}{2\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}}\sqrt{1-\frac{5}{x}}}=$$
$$\frac{4\sqrt{1}+5\sqrt{1}}{2\sqrt{1}\sqrt{1}}=\frac{9}{2}$$

We have our answer based on L'hopital's Rule. I know this was not required, as there is a much easier algebraic manner to solve for the limit, but I thought it was nice trying to find the limit this way.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difference $f(y)-f(z)$ where the difference $y-z$ compared to $y$ and $z$ is small. It sounds like a derivative, so can we try something to make it one? What if we use substitution $h=1/x$?

$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2 + 4x} - \sqrt{x^2 - 5x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} x \left( \sqrt{1 + 4/x} - \sqrt{1 - 5/x} \right) \\
=& \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{1 + 4h} - \sqrt{1 - 5h}}{h}
\end{align}
$$
Now it's almost like the derivative of $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$ at $1$, only that we have different coefficients $1+4h$ and $1-5h$ instead of $1+h$ and $1$ there.

The value of this kind of limit limit is actually $(+4) - (-5)$ times the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ at $1$. (I'll show below why.) The derivative is $g'(x) = 1/(2\sqrt{x})$, so the answer is
$$
9 g'(1) = \frac{9}{2}
$$

---

Here's why you can do this: We will see the two limit exist so splitting the first limit is legal, and then we make a change of variables $s=\alpha h$ and $t=-\beta h$:
$$
\begin{align}
 &\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x_0+\alpha h) - g(x_0+\beta h)}{h}
\\
=&\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x_0+\alpha h) - g(1) + g(1) - g(x_0+\beta h)}{h}
\\
=&
 \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x_0+\alpha h) - g(x_0)}{h}
 - \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x_0 + \beta h) - g(x_0)}{h}
\\= &
 \lim_{s \to 0} \alpha\frac{g(x_0+t) - g(x_0)}{s}
 - \lim_{t \to 0} \beta\frac{g(x_0+t) - g(x_0)}{t}
\\= & \alpha g'(x_0) - \beta g'(x_0) = (\alpha-\beta) g'(x_0)
\end{align}
$$

Addendum: As pointed out in the comments, a shorter way to show this is to define another function $\hat{g}(x) = g(x_0+\alpha x) - g(x_0+\beta x)$ and notice that $\hat{g}(0)=0$ so we have
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x_0+\alpha h) - g(x_0+\beta h)}{h}
= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\hat{g}(h) - \hat{g}(0)}{h} = \hat{g}'(0) = \alpha g'(x_0) - \beta g'(x_0)
$$

Comment: More easily, this is the derivative at $0$ of $f(x)=\sqrt{1+4x}-\sqrt{1-5x}$.

Comment: @egreg I think spotting the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ is easier as an idea. Most of this answer is showing formally the general rule of why and how the coefficients end up as factors of the answer - which would indeed be shorter with your idea. However, I think this is conceptually more straightforward and thus easier even if longer.

Comment: You are essentially proving the chain rule for the particular case. Still easier than other approaches with loads of algebraic manipulations.